# Generating a form dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, document

Hey all
Trying to generate a 1-button form that will go in a cell of a table.  The catch is that this needs to be generated dynamically in javascript.  The table has a couple other values.  I did the table first without the form part and everything was working fine... Now the table doesn't generate at all.

I know the way I'm generating the form is incorrect but I'm not sure why.... Please help!

Thanks

```
function populateInventory() {
        clearTable();  //This works
        var artistIndex = byId('artist').selectedIndex;
        var albumIndex = byId('albumSelect').selectedIndex;
        var inventoryArray = inventoryNames[artistIndex][albumIndex];

        for (i = 0; i < inventoryArray.length; i++) {
            var idValue = inventoryArray[i][2];
            var conditionValue = inventoryArray[i][3];
            var priceValue = inventoryArray[i][4];

            var table = byId('table');
            var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);

            var submitCell = row.insertCell(0);
            var idCell = row.insertCell(1);
            var conditionCell = row.insertCell(2);
            var priceCell = row.insertCell(3);

//Begin problem?!
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.method = "post";
                form.action = "<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];?>";
                var inventoryIdElement = document.createElement("<input name='inventoryIdElement' type='hidden' value='" + idValue + "' ></input>");
                form.appendChild(inventoryIdElement);
                var submitElement = document.createElement("<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Remove' ></input>");
                form.appendChild(submitElement);

            //End problem?!
            var idElement = document.createTextNode(idValue);               
            var conditionElement = document.createTextNode(conditionValue);                 
            var priceElement = document.createTextNode("$" + priceValue);               

            submitCell.appendChild(form);
            idCell.appendChild(idElement);
            conditionCell.appendChild(conditionElement);
            priceCell.appendChild(priceElement);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a good library for DOM manipulation, like jQuery, YUI, Prototype, Dojo, Ext, etc.? It would make your life *much* easier for this sort of things.

Comment: I have... however I need to get this finished quickly and don't have time to learn that.  I will definitely move to something like this after this deadline.  This is the final javascript piece missing..

Comment: In my opinion and experience; beginners tend to learn a library like jQuery much faster than vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using `createElement` properly there. It takes just the tag name, not the whole markup.

Comment: changed it to be like this..
var inventoryIdElement = document.createElement("input");
   inventoryIdElement.name = "inventoryIdElement";
   inventoryIdElement.type = "hidden";
   inventoryIdElement.value = idValue;
   form.appendChild(inventoryIdElement);

Still fail... :(

Comment: The form action gets printed properly.  This is in a php file.